# (iOS) Why does second 'push' segue in navigation controller always crash?

Tags: uitableview, crash, push, storyboard, segue

I have a storyboard setup as a Tabbed Application with first view controller containing a 
UITableView. The Protoype cell has a "push" segue to detail view which is embedded in a navigation controller. So far so good. The detail view pushes when a cell is selected and there is a navigation bar item to get back to the table view.

Now I run into trouble. The detail view has 2 buttons "Map" and "Ticket". If I create a new UIViewController, embed it in a navigation controller, and ctril-drag a 'push' segue from a button to the new view controller as before, the app crashes instantly with a SIGABRT when I click the button. If I don't embed in nav controller and use a 'modal' segue instead it doesn't crash but it seems a natural flow to continue with the 'horizontal slide' animation and the nav bar button back to the detail view.

Once I can stop that crashing I would like to connect the other button to it's own view controller with a UIMapView.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to embed a navigation controller in the detail view. You only need one at the top level. Take out the navigation controller in the detail view controller and just do a push from there to the next view.